# Does 0x limit order has a "Max Orders" limitation?

Tags: 0x

1inch has a max 100 order limitation, does 0x has the same setting
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no limit for number of orders that user can create using ZRX contracts. What could happen is the API limit the number of orders that stores per user, according to ZRX API documentation there is no indicative of such limitation to my knowledge.

Comment: Thanks a lot, are you from 0x team or have you developed based on 0x limit order?

Comment: I am community member building using ZRX stack